# Laravel 4 links

Tags: php, laravel

I need help with my laravel project. I am clearly new to this so please help me understand things. My problem is I don't know what is wrong with my code here. I am trying to access a certain file through this link but it would show an error that the requested url was not found on the server.

For my routes.php

```
Route::get('registration','AdminController@registration');
```

For registration.blade.php

```
 @extends('layouts.master')
 @section('content')

 {{ Form::open(['url'=>'registration']) }}
          <div>
          {{ Form::label('name','Name: ') }} 
          {{ Form::text('name','',['placeholder'=>'Name']) }}          
          </div>
          <div>      
          {{ Form::label('username','Username: ') }} 
          {{ Form::text('username','',['placeholder'=>'Username']) }}
          </div>
          <div>
          {{ Form::label('password','Password: ') }} 
          {{ Form::text('password','',['placeholder'=>'Password']) }}          
          </div>

          <div>
          {{ Form::submit('Register') }}
          </div>
       {{ Form::close() }}
@endsection
```

And for the AdminController.php

```
    <?php

class AdminController extends Basecontroller{

    public function registration()
    {
        return View::make('content.registration');
    }

}
```

What seems to be the problem here? i don't quite get it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I've found the solution for this particular problem. 
My codes, everything work fine, no typos and error so the problem here is my WAMP Server.
For this all to work out, you just have to click wampicon->apache->apachemodule-> then check rewrite_module then restart your WAMP.

Everything would work after that. Hope this might be useful to someone who has the same problem as me.